# AWS Lambda function response type error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function which return a string.The current response is given below.

```
"{\"Details\":[{\"Description\":\"With a low.\",\"stock\":\"1\"}],\"Results\":1,\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"message\":\"Success\"}}"
```

I need to convert it to Json object in AWS API Gateway.How I can do this response conversion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any way you can modify your Lambda function to return an object instead of a string? What language is your Lambda function written in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method available in $util variable `$util.parseJson()`.

ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference

Thanks!